# How to make a text area enabled when selecting a specific item in dropdown menu?

Tags: javascript, html, css

how do i do it? Im having trouble figuring out how to do it. i know it is a condition, but i have no idea how.

```
<form action="update_status.php?serial=<?php echo $_GET['serial']?>" method="post">
                    <fieldset>  
                    <h4>Edit Order Status</h4><br>
                    <div id="">
                        <select name="order_status">
                            <option value="On Process">On Process</option>
                            <option value="Ready for Pickup">Ready for Pickup</option>
                            <option value="To Be Shipped">To Be Shipped</option>
                        </select>                   
                        <label>Tracking Number</label>
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Tracking Number" name="tracking_no" disabled>                     
                        <button type="submit" class="btn">Submit</button>
                    </div> 


                    </fieldset>
                </form>
```

If the user selected To Be Shipped the Tracking Number will be enabled.

Answer (score 1):

Add a `change` handler that checks the value of the `select` and enables or disables the `input` element.

```
document.querySelector('select[name=order_status]')
    .addEventListener('change', function() {
    var trackno = document.querySelector('input[name=tracking_no]');
    if (this.value == 'To Be Shipped') {
        trackno.disabled = false;
    } else {
        trackno.disabled = 'disabled';
    }
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/joa1t1kh/4/)